# Vector of elements satisfying a condition in r project

Tags: r

in code R:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  if (!i %% 2){
    next
  }
  print(i)
}
```

I have as output

```
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 9
```

But I need the vector of i´s that satisfies that condition, ie (1,3,5,7,9).
How can I get the vector (without knowing in advance the vector dimension "length")?

The above is an example of my problem:

```
 x=c(0.1,0.4,0.5)
   y=c(0.2,0.3,0.6,0.7) 

 cont1=0
  for(i in 1:(length(x)+1)){

    for(j in 1:(length(y)+1)){

        if(round((abs((j-1)-(i-1)*(length(y)/length(x))) ),3)  < round( max.v.d,3) ) {
         cont1=cont1+1
         print(paste(i-1,j-1))
          }

    }
  }
```

output

```
[1] "0 0"
[1] "0 1"
[1] "1 1"
[1] "1 2"
[1] "2 2"
[1] "2 3"
[1] "3 3"
[1] "3 4"
```

but, I need a matrix with those elements.

Answer (score 6):

in many ways. Here's one:

```
i <- 1:10
i[as.logical(i%%2)]
```

an alternative:

```
i[(i%%2)==1]
```

a version of that first one for people who hate to type:

```
 i=1:10
 i[!!(i%%2)]
```

If you'll need to do this sort of thing often you should probably write a function, something like this:

```
 odd <- function(x) x%%2 != 0
```

or

```
 even <- function(x) x%%2 == 0
```

... or both. Then you can do stuff like

```
i[odd(i)]
[1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: My general problem is:
how  get "elements" that satisfy a condition in an if () within a for ()

Comment: That's strange; if you need the elements in a vector, R offers a way that avoids having to collect them up like that. R is both more readable and maintainable if you work vectorized. Why are they teaching you to write code that's easy to break? But in any case, the question you actually asked was answered. Perhaps you could ask a new one specifying the restrictions you're operating under  (but you should make it clear what the source of those restrictions is .... it now sounds like this is work for a subject -- you should say so explicitly if you post a new one)